# Getting error when start or restart grafana

Tags: linux, service, grafana, systemd

When I run `sudo systemctl status grafana-server` command to see error messages I get this output

```
 ● grafana-server.service - Grafana instance
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Wed 2022-06-01 14:21:53 CEST; 39s ago
     Docs: http://docs.grafana.org
 Main PID: 61853 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 01 14:21:52 name.dc01.sp.check-dev.de systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
Jun 01 14:21:52 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: Failed to start Grafana instance.
Jun 01 14:21:52 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 01 14:21:52 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Jun 01 14:21:53 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Service hold-off time over, sche
Jun 01 14:21:53 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: Stopped Grafana instance.
Jun 01 14:21:53 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Start request repeated too quick
Jun 01 14:21:53 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: Failed to start Grafana instance.
Jun 01 14:21:53 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 01 14:21:53 name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de systemd[1]: grafana-server.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

I checked logs and seems this cause the error

`cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/grafana/conf/provisioning/plugins/sample.yaml': No such file or directory`

It should install these files why it's trying to find it there instead of just install it?

I have installed grafana before and then I just uninstall it. Now I can't install it again.

Here is log of installation

```
    fatal: [grafana-name.dc01.sps.check-dev.de]: FAILED! => {
"cache_update_time": 1654122323,
"cache_updated": false,
"changed": false,
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "allow_unauthenticated": false,
        "autoclean": false,
        "autoremove": false,
        "cache_valid_time": 0,
        "deb": null,
        "default_release": null,
        "dpkg_options": "force-confdef,force-confold",
        "force": false,
        "force_apt_get": false,
        "install_recommends": null,
        "only_upgrade": false,
        "package": [
            "grafana"
        ],
        "pkg": "grafana",
        "policy_rc_d": null,
        "purge": false,
        "state": "present",
        "update_cache": null,
        "upgrade": null
    }
},
"msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef\" -o \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold\"      install 'grafana'' failed: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)\n",
"rc": 100,
"stderr": "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)\n",
"stderr_lines": [
    "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"
],
"stdout": "Reading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state information...\nThe following NEW packages will be installed:\n  grafana\n0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.\nNeed to get 77.9 MB of archives.\nAfter this operation, 262 MB of additional disk space will be used.\nGet:1 https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable/main amd64 grafana amd64 8.5.4 [77.9 MB]\nFetched 77.9 MB in 1s (41.3 MB/s)\nSelecting previously unselected package grafana.\r\n(Reading database ... \r(Reading database ... 5%\r(Reading database ... 10%\r(Reading database ... 15%\r(Reading database ... 20%\r(Reading database ... 25%\r(Reading database ... 30%\r(Reading database ... 35%\r(Reading database ... 40%\r(Reading database ... 45%\r(Reading database ... 50%\r(Reading database ... 55%\r(Reading database ... 60%\r(Reading database ... 65%\r(Reading database ... 70%\r(Reading database ... 75%\r(Reading database ... 80%\r(Reading database ... 85%\r(Reading database ... 90%\r(Reading database ... 95%\r(Reading database ... 100%\r(Reading database ... 97233 files and directories currently installed.)\r\nPreparing to unpack .../grafana_8.5.4_amd64.deb ...\r\nUnpacking grafana (8.5.4) ...\r\nReplaced by files in installed package grafana-enterprise (8.5.3) ...\r\nProcessing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u13) ...\r\nSetting up grafana (8.5.4) ...\r\ncp: cannot stat '/usr/share/grafana/conf/provisioning/access-control/sample.yaml': No such file or directory\r\ndpkg: error processing package grafana (--configure):\r\n subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1\r\nErrors were encountered while processing:\r\n grafana\r\n",
"stdout_lines": [
    "Reading package lists...",
    "Building dependency tree...",
    "Reading state information...",
    "The following NEW packages will be installed:",
    "  grafana",
    "0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.",
    "Need to get 77.9 MB of archives.",
    "After this operation, 262 MB of additional disk space will be used.",
    "Get:1 https://packages.grafana.com/oss/deb stable/main amd64 grafana amd64 8.5.4 [77.9 MB]",
    "Fetched 77.9 MB in 1s (41.3 MB/s)",
    "Selecting previously unselected package grafana.",
    "(Reading database ... ",
    "(Reading database ... 5%",
    "(Reading database ... 10%",
    "(Reading database ... 15%",
    "(Reading database ... 20%",
    "(Reading database ... 25%",
    "(Reading database ... 30%",
    "(Reading database ... 35%",
    "(Reading database ... 40%",
    "(Reading database ... 45%",
    "(Reading database ... 50%",
    "(Reading database ... 55%",
    "(Reading database ... 60%",
    "(Reading database ... 65%",
    "(Reading database ... 70%",
    "(Reading database ... 75%",
    "(Reading database ... 80%",
    "(Reading database ... 85%",
    "(Reading database ... 90%",
    "(Reading database ... 95%",
    "(Reading database ... 100%",
    "(Reading database ... 97233 files and directories currently installed.)",
    "Preparing to unpack .../grafana_8.5.4_amd64.deb ...",
    "Unpacking grafana (8.5.4) ...",
    "Replaced by files in installed package grafana-enterprise (8.5.3) ...",
    "Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u13) ...",
    "Setting up grafana (8.5.4) ...",
    "cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/grafana/conf/provisioning/access-control/sample.yaml': No such file or directory",
    "dpkg: error processing package grafana (--configure):",
    " subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1",
    "Errors were encountered while processing:",
    " grafana"
]
```

Comment: I found the answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1258104/1007715

Answer (score 1):

Deleting files of grafana from `/var/lib/dpkg/info` helps
After deleting I tried to install grafana again and it works after restart

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/grafana*
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 grafana
sudo apt -f install grafana
```

Comment: This works for me on `Grafana 9.5.2`